# What is the Bernoulli product measure's Radon-Nikodym derivative wrt Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym, bernoulli-distribution

The Bernoulli product measure $\mu$ can be defined for each $p\in (0,1)$ on $\Omega = \{0,1\}^\mathbb N=\{\omega=(\omega_i)|\omega_i\in\{0,1\}, i\in\mathbb N\}=\Pi_{i=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$.  The measure $\mu$ is essentially defined by a collection of Bernoulli random variables $X_i:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ which take the value $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$ depending only on the $i$th coordinate of $\omega\in\Omega$.  The pre-images $X_i^{-1}(0)$ and $X_i^{-1}(1)$ are examples of cylinder sets in the product space and generate the $\sigma$-algebra that the product measure $\mu$ is defined on.

We can then define a map $\Omega\to [0;1]\subset\mathbb R$ by $\omega=(\omega_i)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^\infty \omega_i 2^{-i}$.  Up to a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ having to do with duplicate  binary expansions of the dyadic rationals $k/2^n$ ($k,n\in\mathbb N$), this map identifies $\Omega$ with the unit interval $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$.  The duplicate issue is that dyadic rationals have both an infinite and a terminating binary expansion (in binary, $1/2=0.1=0.0\bar 1$), so the map is not a perfect bijection on that countable set.

We now have two measures on $[0;1]$, $\mu$ and Lebesgue measure $\cal L$.  They are defined on slightly different $\sigma$-algebras since $\cal L$ is defined on the Borel sets and $\mu$ is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets that make the random variables $X_i$ measurable (generated by the cylinder sets).

Is there anything like a Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\cal L$ even though they are not defined on the same $\sigma$-algebras?  For example, is it possible to extend or intersect the $\sigma$-algebras to obtain a useful integral formula with an actual density function so that we could write $$\mu=\nu + \int f d\cal L$$ on some meaningful collection of sets? ($\nu$ a measure singular wrt $\cal L$)

I've looked in a number of books including Billingsley, Chung, Folland, Rudin, Durrett, Cohn, and others.  They discuss the construction of $\mu$, the differences of the $\sigma$-algebras that $\mu$ and $\cal L$ are defined on, but I haven't been able to find any kind of expression of one with respect to the other, if that's possible in some way.

My motivation is to get a better understanding of $\mu$ in more standard analytical terms.

PS: I originally posted this question over in

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619732/what-is-the-bernoulli-product-measures-radon-nikodym-derivative-wrt-lebesgue-me

but it was recommended by a commenter that I post it here instead.

Comment: +1 for the post and also for asking it here.

Comment: For $p \neq 1/2,$ the measure induced by $\omega \to \sum \omega_i 2^{-i}$ on $[0,1]$ is w.r.t. the Lebesgue. [This](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf) develops the idea in section 3 (as exercises, so not great if you're looking for a quick reference, but quite nice if you have the time to work through it).

Comment: thanks @stochasticboy321 ! I'll work through the paper.  on p.13 exercise 34 the paper references a random variable $W$ which doesn't have a density function when $p!=0.5$.  I'm guessing that's related to FZan's Answer below.

Comment: Oh whoops, I meant to say "singular w.r.t. the Lebesgue," kind of an important word to miss out :). But yes, it's very much related, and the ideas are fleshed out through the exercises in a quite pleasant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first start by noting the measure $\mu$ is well defined on all Borel sets.
Take

$$
X  : \Omega \longmapsto \mathbb{R} $$
$$
X=\sum\limits_{i}\frac{X_{n}}{2^{n}}
$$
Note that $\sum\limits^{N}_{i}\frac{X_{i}}{2^{i}}$ are random variables in $\Omega$ so its limit is in fact a random variable. We can then define a measure $\mu_{X}$ in all borel sets by setting $\mu_{X}(B)=\mu(X^{-1}(B))$. We can also get a little bit more intuition on how this measure works by looking on how it assigns measure to dyadic intervals.

Take any dyadic interval $I=[\frac{b}{2^{n}},\frac{b+1}{2^{n}}]$ of level $n$. By writing $b$ in base $2$ we may identify all dyadic intervals of level $n$ with strings of length $n$ in $\{0,1\}^{[[n]]}$. Now for any string $\sigma$ of length $n$ write $I_{\sigma}$ for the respective dyadic interval and $C_{\sigma}$ for the respective cylinder. We'll show by induction on $n$ that $X^{-1}(I_{\sigma})=C_{\sigma}\cup D_{\sigma}$ where $D_{\sigma}$ is a finite set (and thus of measure $0$ in $\Omega$).

The base case $n=1$ is clear if we notice that $X \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]=I_{0}$ if and only if $X_{1}=0$ or $X_{1}=1$ and $X_{i}=0$ for all $i > 1$, similarly for $I_{1}=[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Now suppose we have proved our assertion for $n>1$. Take $\sigma$ any string of length of $n+1$. If $\sigma=0\sigma'$ for $\sigma'$ some string of length $n$, we have that $X \in I_{\sigma}$ if and only if $2X \in I_{\sigma'}$ and $X_{1}=0$. Write $\Omega_{0}=\{\omega \in \Omega: X_{1}=0\}$. The shift operator $$S(\omega)_{n}=\begin{cases} \omega_{0} & n=0 \\
\omega_{n+1}  & \text{all other cases}
 \end{cases}$$

is a bijection from $\Omega$ to $\Omega_{0}$, furthermore, $S(C_{\rho})=C_{0\rho}$ for any string $\rho$. Now

$$2X|_{\Omega_{0}}=\sum\limits_{i}\frac{X_{i}}{2^{i-1}}=X \circ S^{-1}$$

So $$X^{-1}(I_{\sigma})=2X|_{\Omega_{0}}(I_{\sigma'})=(X \circ S^{-1})^{-1}(I_{\sigma'})=S(X(I_{\sigma'}))=S(C_{\sigma'}\cup D_{\sigma'})=C_{\sigma} \cup S(D_{\sigma'})$$

Here we used the inductive hypothesis on $X^{-1}(I_{\sigma})$.
The case where $\sigma=1\sigma'$ can be done similarly by instead noting that $X^{-1}(I_{\sigma})=(2X-1)|_{\Omega_{1}}^{-1}(I_{\sigma'})$ where $\Omega_{1}=\{\omega \in \Omega : X_{1} = 1\}$. This completes the induction.

It is now clear that $\mu_{X}(I_\sigma)=p^{\sum\sigma_{i}}(1-p)^{\sum (1-\sigma_{i})}$

There is also a more "within $\mathbb{R}$" approach to finding the same measure through [Carathéodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). By assigning this probability to each dyadic interval, we can construct exactly the same measure. Moreover in the special case where $p=\frac{1}{2}$, the uniqueness of the extension guarantees $\mu_{X}=\mathcal{L}$. Sadly that as far as we can go as for establishing relationships with $\mathcal{L}$.

For $p$ and $q$ write $\mu_{p}$ and $\mu_{q}$ for the measures constructed as we did above for Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p$ and $q$ respectively. We can prove that if $p \neq q$ then $\mu_{p}$ and $\mu_{q}$ are mutually singular, in particular if $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$, $\mu_{p}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ are mutually singular so Radon-Nikodym tells us little about $\mu_{p}$.

For a real number $x$ write $x_{i}$ for the $i$-th term in the binary expansion. By looking a carefully on how $\mu_{X}$ assigns probability to dyadic intervals, we can show that the functions $f_{i}(x)=x_{i}$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$ when looked at with respect to $\mu_{p}$ and of parameter $q$ with respect to the measure $\mu_{q}$.
Thus, by the law of large numbers, the sets $A_{p}=\{ x \in  \mathbb{R} : \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sum^{n}x_{i}}{n}=p\}$ and $A_{q}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sum^{n}x_{i}}{n}=q\}$ fulfill

$$
\mu_{p}(A_{p})=1 $$
$$
\mu_{q}(A_{q})=1   
$$

So $\mu_{p}$ and $\mu_{q}$ are mutually singular.

There is a little bit of discussion of the characteristics of these measures and of the sets $A_{p}$ from a fractal geometry perspective in first chapter of:

*Bishop, Christopher J.; Peres, Yuval*, [**Fractals in probability and analysis**](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316460238), Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics 162. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-13411-9/hbk; 978-1-316-46023-8/ebook). ix, 402 p. (2017). [ZBL1390.28012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1390.28012).

Comment: Thanks @FZan !  I need to work through your response in more detail.  The upshot seems to be that since $\mu$ ($p!=0$) and $\cal L$ are are mutually singular there is no integral component in the Radon-Nikodym representation.  It's a little counter-intuitive to me since $\mu$ assigns positive measure to many intervals with interior, but then maybe that shouldn't surprise me.

Comment: For those interested, there is an online version of the Bishop + Peres books: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math324.F15/book1Dec15.pdf

Comment: I really appreciate this answer and I'm working through it.  Here's where I'm stuck atm: if $\mu_X(I_\sigma)=p^{\sum\sigma_i}(1-p)^{\sum(1-\sigma_i)}>0$ and $\mathcal{L}(I_\sigma)>0$ (i.e., $\mathcal{L}$ being Lebesgue measure, aka $\mu_{1/2}$) how can those two measures be mutually singular? The definition of mutual singularity is "measures μ, ν are said to be mutually singular if there exists a measurable set s such that μ s = 0 and ν sᶜ = 0." so I would expect they can't both be positive on a Borel set with non-empty interior.

Comment: "so I would expect they can't both be positive on a Borel set with non-empty interior. " This not necessarily the case, for example any two probability measures on $[0,1]$ must have $\mu([0,1])=\nu([0,1])=1$,  mutually singular or not. They can have the same support even.

Comment: In this case we have $\mu_{p}(A_{p}^c)=0$ and $ A_{q}\subseteq A_{p}^c$ so $ \mu_{q}(A_{p})=0$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion @FZan.  For those interested, the reference provided earlier (https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math324.F15/book1Dec15.pdf) has some good graphs in section 1.3 ("sets defined by digit restrictions") and section 1.5 ("sets defined by digit frequency").  For instance, there's a histogram of $\mu_{1/3}$ on dyadic intervals of length $2^{-7}$ and other interesting results.